# How and Where to process AkkaPersistence persisted Events to make the information valuable and meaningful to the responsive UI?

Tags: scala, cqrs, event-sourcing, responsiveness, akka-persistence

I am quite familiar with how the **PersistentActor** and **PersistentView** work while implementing **Akka Persistence**.

Consider the following example with the idea as far as I understand.

A Scala case class **Contact**.

```
case class Contact(id: String, version: Int, fName: String, lName: String, age: Int)
```

The PersistentActor persisted events in the journal are :

```
ContactCreated("123af-232ff-232d", 1, "john", "doe", 25)
FirstNameChanged("123af-232ff-232d", 2, "jan")
AgeChanged("123af-232ff-232d", 3, 27)
FirstNameChanged("123af-232ff-232d", 4, "janet")
```

Every time the commands are sent from the responsive UI, such new events are persisted if validation succeeds 202 CommandAccepted or any CommandValidationError being fired back.

But without significant delay in the responsive environment, the UI must be able to query the **REST API backend** and show the latest **Contact object** after the backend **WebSocket push** informs the UI that UUID "123af-232ff-232d" is available for read:

```
Contact("123af-232ff-232d", 4, "janet", "doe", 27)
```

This result should happen after merging all the events with the latest data available as I understand.

So, my actual concern is: **How and where in this backend application I do the processing of those events as soon as they are generated, merge those data, and store the merged data for reading by the query side.**

Many many thanks in advance if some could shed light on implementing or correcting my thought.

Comment: Please also correct me if I have misunderstood the flow from the frontend to the backend and vice-versa in a reactive responsive application.

Comment: Is it where I have to maintain the current state inside the PersistentActor by merging each generated events after they are persisted? and immediately send a GET query command from the UI to read the current state and display the data?

Comment: ...but still... before sending GET query, UI needs to know that the current state is available...

Answer (score 0):

The current state of `Contact` might not be so much a view as the actual state, and in the view you will not accept eventual consistency which will be the case with a view.

I would keep that as *the* state inside the persistent actor and allow for a query against the actor to get the current `Contact` and use that.

Comment: For example I need to query a list of contacts, is it not too heavy to maintain the 'contactList' state inside PersistentActor in memory?

Comment: I found the link to my answers:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/MNDc9cVG1To

Akka Persistence on the Query Side: The Conclusion